# textbox output to text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tabbed page  where a user inputs a dollar amount into a text box and that amount is displayed in a label above the tabs. There are two tabs where the user can change the dollar amount. I can get the amounts to change between the tabs:

```
     $(function(){

 $('#damountBox').keyup(function() {
 $('.dab1').val($(this).val());
 });

 $('#damountBox1').keyup(function() {
    $('.dab').val($(this).val());
   });
  });
```

I can get the amount to display correctly in the label with one text box:

```
    $(function(){
     $('#damountBox').keyup(function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
     $('#firstOut').text(('Donation: $') + (+$('#damountBox').val()));
     }, 50);
  });
});
```

But when trying to get them to all work together, that's another problem. My goal is to have the label update and show the dollar amount entered no matter which tab text box its entered into.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHLNA/1/) of what I got thus far

Comment: you want your label to reflect value on change event or on keyup event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#damountBox').change(function() {
     $('#damountBox1').val($(this).val());
     $('#damountdata').text(('Donation: $') + (+$('#damountBox').val()));
});

$('#damountBox1').change(function() {
    $('#damountBox').val($(this).val());
    $('#damountdata').text(('Donation: $') + (+$('#damountBox1').val()));
});
```